# How to avoid adjusting the width, height of rows and columns in Datagrid by user

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to avoid adjusting the width, height of rows and columns in `DataGrid` by user

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<DataGrid 
   Name="MarkDG" 
   ItemsSource="{StaticResource Marks}" 
   IsReadOnly="True" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="323,179,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   ColumnWidth="150" 
   HeadersVisibility="Column" 
   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
   FrozenColumnCount="1">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=StuNo}" Header="Student No" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MarkSet}" Header="Mark Obtained"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Initially `DataGrid` appears to be
[image]
But the user can move the `DataGrid` as shown below
[image]
How to avoid such situation?

Comment: Thank you I will correct the formatting in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable column and/or row resizing by the user set [`CanUserResizeColumns="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserresizerows.aspx) and [`CanUserResizeRows="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserresizecolumns.aspx) against you `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ... CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"/>
```